# Garbled font on tty1 (but not tty2-6) after booting

Tags: opensuse, tty, fonts

Running the latest OpenSUSE Tumbleweed, near the end of boot tty1's font gets completely scrambled (see the picture below). It's fine until shortly after mounting /, and the other ttys work just fine. tty2-6 are running the same command (`/sbin/agetty --noclear $TTY linux`) and have the same environment as tty1. `/etc/sysconfig/console` has the default settings for everything ("UTF-8" for encoding and "" for everything else).

I can fix it after boot by running "setfont", but if something goes wrong during boot this leaves me completely helpless, so I'd like to stop it from happening in the first place.

[image: the colours show up right but the actual text is completely messed up]

Answer (score 0):

Change the terminal assignment in `/etc/default/grub` to

```
terminal=console
```

and delete the

```
splash=silent quiet
```

and replace with

```
nomode set
```

in the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` assignments